# Get Audio Blob from AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AJAX to retrieve a WAV file from AWS S3 that was previously uploaded using the CORS/FormData method found [here](http://bencoe.tumblr.com/post/30685403088/browser-side-amazon-s3-uploads-using-cors). I seem to be getting the data just fine, but when I try to create a Blob from the body of the object returned from S3's `getObject` and link it to an `audio` tag via `createObjectURL`, the file doesn't play.

Any pointers on bridging the gap from the buffer response from `getObject` to playing the audio in the `audio` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was to [get a signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) for the audio file.